# How do I hide certain sprites in Sprite Select Window in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

In Unity (2019.2.0f1) it is possible to select a sprite for a gameobject by going to the Inspector -> Sprite Renderer -> Sprite, then click on the round symbol (See Screenshot).

[image]

This opens the Sprite Select Window and you can chose a sprite from your assets. By clicking on the eye in the top tight corner, you can hide certain sprites (See Screenshot).

[image]

For me the 16 hidden packages are there by default.
My question is:

How can I hide a few of my own sprites / packages(?), so the Sprite Select Window is less crowded with sprites I would never select from here?

Comment: I haven't seen that option before. Interesting. I suspect its based on assembly definitions. What actually shows up when you click that button?

Comment: For example it shows items that are located under Assets -> Packages -> 2D Tilemap Editor -> Tests -> Sprites -> 1103034 -> 1103034_n (with n being an int number between 0 and 63). It looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/ymMnVkA (I never installed that package and do not know why it is part of my 2D project)

Comment: When you created your 2D project, Unity likely automatically included the 2D Tilemap Editor package for you. That's where those are coming from. But you still didn't do what I asked. You are HOVERING over the button, what happens if you CLICK it?

Comment: which Unity version is this? oh ok seems to be something new in 2019.2

Comment: It seems to hide **all** packages you imported via the package manager (at least those that contain sprites)! For there are 14 hidden packages which equals exactly the number of packages in the project. I guess Unity simply wanted to hide icons and stuff from the packages to not confuse the user and make us wonder where all those sprites came from. I don't think you can configure this manually for your sprites

Comment: Yeah, that is what I also assumed. I did what you asked for. In the link (https://imgur.com/a/ymMnVkA) you can see the result of me pressing the button. It shows the 2D Tilemaps with the name 1103034_n (with n being an int number between 0 and 63 (only 53 visible in the screenshot)). It also shows other sprites from other locations that are also located in my Package folder. You see, the result is not only 16 more sprites, but way more. This is because it hides whole packages and I would like to be able to do the same with my own sprites.

Comment: well you could pack all your own sprites in a [package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CustomPackages.html) and then include this package again in your project via the package manager (`Packages/manifest.json`) (not confuse with the unitypackage you can export) ... however this seems to be a bit overkill for just hiding some sprites in this specific window (or maybe others)

Answer (score -1):

I have a simple solution for this. Open the folder which you want to hide and make folder **hidden**. then restart unity.(recompile works too)